# Project Euler # 30 Digits fifth power in Python

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

> Surprisingly there are only three numbers that can be written as the sum of fourth powers of their digits:
>
> - \$1634 = 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4\$
> - \$8208 = 8^4 + 2^4 + 0^4 + 8^4\$
> - \$9474 = 9^4 + 4^4 + 7^4 + 4^4\$
>
> As 1 = 1^4 is not a sum it is not included.
>
> The sum of these numbers is \$1634 + 8208 + 9474 = 19316\$.
>
> Find the sum of all the numbers that can be written as the sum of fifth powers of their digits.

```
from time import time


def powers(n, power):
    """Assumes n and power integers > 0.
    generates all numbers up to n if total(n digits ** power) = number."""
    nums_pows = {number: sum(int(digit) ** power for digit in str(number)) for number in range(2, n)}
    return (x for x, y in nums_pows.items() if x == y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time()
    print(sum(powers(1000000, 5)))
    print(f'Time: {time() - start_time} seconds.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your comprehensions are hard to understand, as you have two on one line. I recomend you spread them over multiple lines to increase readability.
- There is no benifit to using a dictionary comprehension, and only makes me think you're abusing comprehensions.

  Just use a normal `for` loop and use `yield`.
- You don't need to pass `n`, you can find the limit by using `power * 9**power`.
  This causes the program to run in a quarter of the time.

```
def powers(power):
    for number in range(2, power * 9**power):
        total = sum(int(digit) ** power for digit in str(number))
        if total == number:
            yield number
```

If you change from using `range` to just digits and checking that the total is an anagram of the input then you can get the code to run in ~5% the time of the previous code.

```
def powers(power):
    for size in range(1, len(str(power * 9**power)) + 1):
        for digits in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(10), size):
            total = sum(int(digit) ** power for digit in digits)
            if (sorted(str(total)) == sorted(str(digit) for digit in digits)
                and total != 1
            ):
                yield total
```